# How do to start with clean Managed Object Context without deleting objects in Core Data

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-data, swift4

You will have to forgive me, there will likely be no code in this question as I don't know what I would include for this question, so please bare with my explanation.

Here's the background, I am in the process of making a fitness application where users can create their own workouts. I have exercises saving successfully into workouts, and have those workouts successfully saving as well in. While making a workout, a list of the exercises created by the user for that workout is provided in a table view, which is populated from core data.

Where my issue arises is when I try to create another workout, it still displays the exercises from the previous workouts in the table view even though they were not created for this workout. As a result the user would have to manually delete all the old exercises before adding new ones. Through some testing I've discovered that the table only gets information to populate it after running my fetch() function which means it's likely grabbing ALL exercises from my persistant storage container. How do I make the table empty every time I create a new workout without sacrificing the saved exercises in place?

Thank you for your patience if you've made it this far.

Comment: All databases can filter data with predicates. Add an appropriate `NSPredicate` to your `NSFetchRequest`

Comment: Your `Workout` should have a reference field to its `Exercise`s. When you start a new workout that list will be empty.

Answer (score 1):

A "clean" managed object context doesn't make sense, because the whole purpose of the context is to access the persistent store. If it's in the store, the context can find it, and will find it if you run the right fetch.

Since you have workouts and exercises, you probably want to have a one-to-many relationship from `Workout` to `Exercise`. Every `Workout` could have multiple related `Exercise` objects, and each `Exercise` would have only one workout. You could then get all exercises for a workout by getting the value of this relationship.

The view controller you describe would show all exercises that are related to a specific workout. If it's a new `Workout`, there wouldn't be any exercises yet, so the list would be empty. As you add exercises, you'd update the relationship, and only the current workout's exercises would appear in the list.

You may find it useful to review [Creating Managed Object Relationships](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/HowManagedObjectsarerelated.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH17-SW1), from Apple's Core Data programming guide.